# How to return the value to HTML from JSP

Tags: java, jsp

**Root Issue**: Unable to get the value in JSP sent by the HTML xhr request.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
    function click() {
        var xhr = null;
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        xhr.open('POST', "verify.jsp", true);
        var params = 'empIds=' + '123';
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);

            }
        };
        xhr.send(params);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button onclick="click()" type="button">Click</button></p>
```

JSP Page

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<HTML>
<HEAD>   
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<BR>
   <%
      long timeInMilliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
      String empId = request.getParameter("empIds");
      out.print("emp Id: "+empId);
    %>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Actual Result:

```
empId:
```

Expected Result:

```
empId: 123
```

Please help me where i did the mistake or how to fix it. Basically want to send the value from HTML to JSP. JSP should retrieve the value and send the same value back to HTML

```
Reason: String empId = request.getParameter("empIds"); is returning null.
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community The request.getParameter returns null though the value has been sent in xhr request from HTML. I am unable to retrieve the value sent from HTML in jsp page

Comment: @Community I have modified the question too. Please review and advice how to fix it

Comment: @Community Any answers for the above?